# Before the BlocListener occur, the state has updated in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

Top of the widget tree I have blocprovider with "lazy: False" parameter (authCubit) and with this, I can immediately listen to the auth changes.

I also have a landing page, and it's exactly using BlocListener. The problem is, first the state is coming false from the firebase auth (user is null), then it will come as true (user is firebase user). Because of that, the BlocListener does not listen to the state and does nothing. I tried to catch it with "listenWhen" property, but I couldn't do it.

I also checked that when the app restarted, the user is not null, it comes as FirebaseUser.

In the landingPage which has the related blocListener, I tried to use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback for controlling the state, but I couldn't handle it.

```
late StreamSubscription<AuthUserModel>? _authUserSubscription;

_authUserSubscription = _authService.authStateChanges.listen(_listenAuthStateChangesStream);

  Future<void> _listenAuthStateChangesStream(AuthUserModel authUser) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(isInProgress: true));

    if (AuthUserModel.empty() == authUser) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          authUser: authUser,
          isUserLoggedIn: false,
          isInProgress: false,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      await _chatService.connectTheCurrentUser();

      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          authUser: authUser,
          isUserLoggedIn: true,
          isInProgress: false,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

and my infrastructure layer,

```
  @override
  Stream<AuthUserModel> get authStateChanges {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(
      (User? user) {
        if (user == null) {
          return AuthUserModel.empty();
        } else {
          return user.toDomain();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

So, you can ask how do you use the blocProvider and bloc listener.

BlocProvider in the top of the widget tree:

```
 BlocProvider(
          lazy: false,
          create: (context) => getIt<AuthCubit>(),
          
      
      child: Listener(
        onPointerUp: (_) {
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            final FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
            }
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp.router(...
```

Finally, BlocListener here:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.isUserLoggedIn) {
          context.go(context.namedLocation("channels_page"));
        } else {
          context.go(context.namedLocation("sign_in_page"));
        }
      },
      child: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CustomProgressIndicator(
            progressIndicatorColor: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I do not really understand your problem description. However, if you do not "feel" the state change in the app, a possible cause could be that you are not using `Equatable` for the state. When using `copyWith` the app will not notice the state change and will not emit the new state (unless you are using a complicated workaround for not using Equatable)

Comment: So let me give more details. Think as you are opening the app for the first time. Then, there are 2 ways. First, If you authenticated, you should go to the home page, and otherwise you should go to the login page. So, I checked that in the service section, I authenticated, I am sure about that. So, I should go to the home page, but it redirected me to the login page because the state is not updated to the "user logged in". I am deciding the page with user's state via BlocListener, and I use freezed package with my cubits. @w461

Comment: So this could result from the emit not being executed when bloc does not recognize the state change. Are you using Equatable. If not, this is the first you should try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked if the user checked from the auth service or not. With this, since we update our state before the BlocListener, we can check after the BlocListener, our state is what. Then, we can do some things using the information that is exactly the state before the BlocListener occurs and after the BlocListener occurs.

```
  listenWhen: (p, c) =>
      p.isUserCheckedFromAuthService != c.isUserCheckedFromAuthService &&
      c.isUserCheckedFromAuthService,
```

So, the related function is like this:

```
  Future<void> _listenAuthStateChangesStream(AuthUserModel authUser) async {
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        isInProgress: true,
        authUser: authUser,
        isUserCheckedFromAuthService: true,
      ),
    );

    if (state.isLoggedIn) {
      await _chatService.connectTheCurrentUser();

      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          authUser: authUser,
          isInProgress: false,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```